React Context - Accessing state in a component is undefined
I'm building a React application that fetches job data from an API and displays it in a CurrentOpeningsCard component. I'm using Context to manage the job data across components. However, I'm encountering that the state used with context is undefined in CurrentOpeningsCard component.
// ProviderCurrentOpenings .jsx
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const currentJobsContext = createContext();

const ProviderCurrentOpenings = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentJobs, setcurrentJobs] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/search',
  };

  const fetchcurrentJobs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.request(options);
      setcurrentJobs(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchcurrentJobs();
  }, []);

  return (
    <currentJobsContext.Provider value={currentJobs}>
      {children}
    </currentJobsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProviderCurrentOpenings;

// CurrentOpeningsCard .jsx
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { currentJobsContext } from './ProviderCurrentOpenings'

const CurrentOpeningsCard = () => {
    const { currentJobs } = useContext(currentJobsContext)
    console.log(currentJobs)
  return (
      <>
          {currentJobs && currentJobs.map && currentJobs?.map((job, index) => {
              return (
                  ... //code
              )
          })
          }
      </>
  )
}

export default CurrentOpeningsCard

// App. jsx
//other imports

import JobProvider from './context/JobProvider'
import TrendingJobsProvider from './components/TrendingJobsComponent/TrendingJobsProvider'
import ProviderCurrentOpenings from './components/currentopenings/ProviderCurrentOpenings'
import CurrentJobOpenings from './components/currentopenings/CurrentJobOpenings'


const App = () => {
  return (
    <JobProvider>
      <TrendingJobsProvider>
        <ProviderCurrentOpenings>
    <div className='max-w-[100vw] h-[100svh]'>
      <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/trendingjobs' element={<TrendingJobs />}/>
        <Route path='/currentjobs' element={<CurrentJobOpenings />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
        </ProviderCurrentOpenings>
      </TrendingJobsProvider>
    </JobProvider>
  )
}

export default App

still can't figure out why the currentJobs state showing as it is undefined.

setcurrentJobs(data) and immediately
console.log(currentJobs) will not do what you think it will.

currentJobs is a constant which contains a snapshot of what the state used to be at the time of rendering. It will never change. Calling setcurrentJobs does not change it, it just asks react to render the component again. Future renders will get their own snapshots with the updated values. If you'd like to verify that the component rerenders, try moving your console.log statement to the body of the component.

@NicholasTower the question is edited

@ChukwujiobiCanon read the question again

You probably should check up on response.data first before invoking setcurrentJobs() with it as argument.
@NicholasTower obligatory nitpick; currentJobs is a const reference to a value. The rest of what Nicholas said is exactly the mechanism.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I logged response.data and it showed the data, but when I passed the currentJobs state with useContext it shows undefined. If the data hadn't set, it would have shown empty array as the state default value is [] ,not undefined

Yea good point.

Where do you render the JSX ProviderCurrentOpenings? Share your code for that.

@ChukwujiobiCanon ProviderCurrentOpenings is a context provider, and I am rendering the currentJobs state in CurrentOpeningsCard. the needed code is already provided

I didn’t mean to offend you. All I’m saying is that if CurrentOpeningsCard is not rendered as a child of the Provider, then there will be no context.

@ChukwujiobiCanon maybe the problem is with wrapping the child components with ProviderCurrentOpenings wrapper in the App.jsx
.Now you can see the ProviderCurrentOpenings in App.jsx. I have edited

I tried this, and it worked for me

Creating the Context

Create a new context with an empty array as the default value and a provider component that fetches data from an API and updates the context value.
import axios from 'axios';
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, ReactNode } from 'react';

export const currentJobsContext = createContext([]); // Default value is an empty array

const ProviderCurrentOpenings = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [currentJobs, setCurrentJobs] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  };

  const fetchCurrentJobs = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.request(options);
      setCurrentJobs(response.data); // Update state with the fetched data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCurrentJobs(); // Fetch data on component mount
  }, []);

  return (
    <currentJobsContext.Provider value={currentJobs}>
      {children}
    </currentJobsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProviderCurrentOpenings;




Using the Context

Access the context value in your component without destructuring to handle the initial state and update it properly.
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { currentJobsContext } from './ProviderCurrentOpenings';

const CurrentOpeningsCard = () => {
  const currentJobs = useContext(currentJobsContext); // Access context value directly

  console.log(currentJobs); // Initially an empty array, then the API response data

  return (
    <div>
      {currentJobs.length > 0 ? (
        currentJobs.map(job => (
          <div key={job.id}>
            <h3>{job.name}</h3>
            <p>{job.email}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CurrentOpeningsCard;

It changes the default value to API response data.

Now I m getting another issue, I have edited the question

update the answer

that can't work out. adding checks to map function is not the problem. the problem is that when you are console logging the console.log(currentJobs) in CurrentOpeningsCard.jsx, currentJobs is undefined. however the default value of the state is []

is it remain undefined or, undefined chnage to the api response

Here, he is destructing the const { currentJobs } = useContext(currentJobsContext), but in my example, I showed it as this without destructring. and initially the currentJobs will be a default value, then the data will populated
